# Why am I getting objects printed twice?

Tags: ruby, irb

When I am in irb or in rails and I create some iteration with `each`, I am getting the whole struct printed again in my terminal or inside the browser. Example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

a.each do |number|
  puts n
end
```

The result in irb terminal or inside the browser:

```
1
2
3
4

=> [1,2,3,4]
```

Why does this `=> [1,2,3,4]` appear inside the browser? I can't create a single list in my page because the whole structure appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every expression in Ruby returns a value; in `irb`, the value returned by the expression you've just executed is displayed after `=>`.

The return value of `Enumerable::each` is the object that called `each` - in this case, the array `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Thanks! What have i to do to don't get this behavior inside my app? Inside the browser i see the populated list and this hole struct again...

Comment: At a guess, you have something like `<%= a.each {|n| puts n} %>`. In which case, the `=` means Rails will output the value of the expression - `a`, as discussed. Your best bet is probably `<%= a.join("\n") %>` or similar.

Comment: Thank you! I see the problem now! You all are so smart! Knowing about the returning behavior i undertood that the error is coming from this "=" signal. The correct structure must be <% code %> html <% end %>

Answer (score 0):

You see them printed twice: once as *side effect*, second time as the *return value*. irb always `puts` the last return value. The return value for `each` is its receiver. You cannot avoid that when using irb, but they will not show up when you run the script as standalone software. The First `1`, ..., `4` are the outputs of your `puts`. They are called side effects.

Comment: Thank you for the answear. Now i need to avoid this double printing inside the browser, inside rails app. I'm using this iterations to populate a list (<ul>) and i'm getting the correct list and the whole struct again, printed after the list...just like in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Because ruby returns in everything even blocks. So your each statement is returning. You're seeing it output because irb shows you the return of everything. In a script it would only output once.

Answer (score 0):

Run it outside `irb`, and you shall be enlightened.

```
ruby -e `[1,2,3,4].each {|ele| puts ele}`
```